# changing drive from simple to primary

Tags: windows-8.1

Whilst trying to dual boot kali linux with windows 8.1, I accidentally changed my drives from primary to simple:

[image: Please see here for screenshot],

How do I change it back to primary to simple? i.e. from dynamic to basic, without losing data?

Comment: You cannot do this with Disk Management itself. But all of the known hard drive partitioning tools (Mini Tool and EaseUS to name two).